# How to configure .env file in Docker-Compose in React?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerignore

I have added `.env` in docker ignore and after image is built environment variable is undefined, So how can I configure those environment variable in `docker-compose.yml` file

*Should we also put `docker-compose.yml` in the ignore ?*

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services: 
    client:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        command: npm start
        container_name: testReact
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"        
        volumes: 
            - ./:/app
            - /app/node_modules
```

**.env**

```
REACT_APP_CONSTANT = 'MY REACT APP'
```

**.dockerignore**

```
/node_modules
/build
.git
*.md
.gitignore
.env
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're using the `.env` file without declaring variables in the docker-compose.yml.

The `.env` is special and, if not declared in a `env_file` subsection, it's used to replace variables in the docker-compose.yml (check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) for more info).

The solution would be to add and `environment` subsection. e.g.

```yaml
version: '3'
services: 
    client:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        command: npm start
        container_name: testReact
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"        
        volumes: 
            - ./:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        environment:
            - REACT_APP_CONSTANT
```

note: you can also use the object notation in the `environment` subsection. This helps defining default values. e.g.:

```yaml
        environment:
            REACT_APP_CONSTANT: ${REACT_APP_CONSTANT:-'another default'}
```

EDIT:
btw remove the spaces from the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables in docker-compose.yml by adding the 'environment' key, like this:

```
version: '3'
services: 
    client:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        command: npm start
        container_name: testReact
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"        
        volumes: 
            - ./:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        environment:
            - REACT_APP_CONSTANT=MY-REACT-APP
```

But if it's a secret, it's better not to push it to git. You could simply use your `.env` file as usual and not put it to `.dockerignore` or another and the preferred way would be to use Docker secrets.

Here is a [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) on it

Comment: the docker-compose is malformed, the entries in the environment subsection shouldn't have spaces around `=`. it should read `REACT_APP_CONSTANT=MY REACT APP`.

Comment: if env has secret should i put docker-compose.yml in .dockerignore ?

Comment: no, it makes no sense. .dockerignore file is used for telling docker which files to omit when doing operations like `COPY . /www`. What you really need is to avoid pushing secrets to git, usually .env file is in .gitignore anyway, but you should double-check that.