# How to using docker-compose with environment

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have node application that build into an image. This image not contain .env file because I add it on .gitignore whereas the application need it. How can I configure this environment on docker-compose?

I've read some of example but still dont get it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569928/how-to-configure-env-file-in-docker-compose-in-react) question has same problem with me but it still doesn't work.

**docker-compose:**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  node:
    container_name: node-app
    image: node_app:latest
    ports:
      - 3334:3333
    environment:
      - HOST=127.0.0.1
      - PORT=3333
      - NODE_ENV=dummy
      - APP_NAME=AdonisJs
      - CACHE_VIEWS=false
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_DATABASE=database
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm i -g @adonisjs/cli
RUN npm install

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3333
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Everytime I run `docker-compose up` its ended up with this.

```
WARNING: The HOST variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Recreating node-app_node_1 ... done
Attaching to node-app_node_1
node_1  | 
node_1  | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/.env'
node_1  | 
node_1  | 
node_1  | 1 Env.load
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/framework/src/Env/index.js:110
node_1  | 
node_1  | 2 new Env
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/framework/src/Env/index.js:42
node_1  | 
node_1  | 3 Object.closure
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/framework/providers/AppProvider.js:29
node_1  | 
node_1  | 4 Ioc._resolveBinding
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:231
node_1  | 
node_1  | 5 Ioc.use
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Ioc/index.js:731
node_1  | 
node_1  | 6 AppProvider.boot
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/framework/providers/AppProvider.js:337
node_1  | 
node_1  | 7 anonymous
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Registrar/index.js:147
node_1  | 
node_1  | 8 arrayMap
node_1  |   /usr/src/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:653
node_1  | 
node-app_node_1 exited with code 1
```

All I know that docker-compose environment pass to the variable that called just as same as we define to get the value, but there is not .env file on the image to called the variable. What I have to do to make the docker-compose can pass the environment to the app? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ENOENT indicates that node is looking for a file at /usr/src/app/.env but there is nothing there. Try adding

```
RUN touch /usr/src/app/.env
```

to your Dockerfile and see if having an empty .env file fixes it.